# Why is my Wi-Fi connection saying "no account found" when I try to connect via wireless networks?

Tags: networking, wi-fi, router, troubleshooting

I have enabled Wi-Fi.  I try connecting to various networks, and during the IP address obtaining process, the notification will popup from the Wi-Fi app saying:

"No account for ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** network. Try again."

It does this with many different Wi-Fi apps, including the stock app (the one that comes default), other apps, etc. It also does this with any network, within range, yes, and still the same problem arises. I checked all system written logs and there's no errors, or anything that could explain this issue.

There's nothing wrong, I believe, with the hardware on my phone, nor the software(for the most part).

However, this has been suddenly happening with any wireless network. What could be causing this?

Comment: Voting to close as *off-topic*, because questions about Android devices do not belong on Super User. See the [help/on-topic] for details. This question will be migrated to [android.se] shortly; please do not cross-post, as this will happen automatically once enough close votes have been cast on this question. To ensure you retain control of the question, please create an account at [android.se] and associate it with your Super User account.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://goo.gl/5UGEDT from an hour earlier. Wherever this ends up, could be an android OS or even carrier software update